# In-App Review flow not showing only in Production

Tags: android, testing, production, review

I am trying to implement In-App review for an Android application. I implemented as per official documentation and I tested it using Internal App Sharing procedure and it worked correctly. Does anyone have any information why it might not show the review window in production environment for other users that already have the application installed?